# Create array of values from specific element in XML using Python

Tags: python, xml, anaconda

I have an XML file which has many elements. I would like to create a list/array of all the values which have a specific element name, in my case "pair:ApplicationNumber".

I've gone over a lot of the other questions however I am not able to find an answer. I know that I can do this by loading the text file and going over it using pandas however, I'm sure there's a much better way.

I was unsuccessful trying ElementTree as well as XML.Dom using minidom

My code currently looks as follows:

```
import os
from xml.dom import minidom
WindowsUser = os.getenv('username')
XMLPath = os.path.join('C:\\Users', WindowsUser, 'Downloads', 'ApplicationsByCustomerNumber.xml')
xmldoc = minidom.parse(XMLPath)
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('pair:ApplicationNumber')
for s in itemlist:
    print(s.attributes['pair:ApplicationNumber'].value)
```

an example XML file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pair:PatentApplicationList xsi:schemaLocation="urn:us:gov:uspto:pair PatentApplicationList.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:pair="urn:us:gov:uspto:pair">
    <pair:FileHeader>
            <pair:FileCreationTimeStamp>2017-07-10T10:52:12.12</pair:FileCreationTimeStamp>
    </pair:FileHeader>
    <pair:ApplicationStatusData>
        <pair:ApplicationNumber>62383607</pair:ApplicationNumber>
        <pair:ApplicationStatusCode>20</pair:ApplicationStatusCode>
        <pair:ApplicationStatusText>Application Dispatched from Preexam, Not Yet Docketed</pair:ApplicationStatusText>
        <pair:ApplicationStatusDate>2016-09-16</pair:ApplicationStatusDate>
        <pair:AttorneyDocketNumber>1354-T-02-US</pair:AttorneyDocketNumber>
        <pair:FilingDate>2016-09-06</pair:FilingDate>
        <pair:LastModifiedTimestamp>2017-05-30T21:40:37.37</pair:LastModifiedTimestamp>
        <pair:CustomerNumber>122761</pair:CustomerNumber><pair:LastFileHistoryTransaction>
            <pair:LastTransactionDate>2017-05-30</pair:LastTransactionDate>
            <pair:LastTransactionDescription>Email Notification</pair:LastTransactionDescription> </pair:LastFileHistoryTransaction> 
        <pair:ImageAvailabilityIndicator>true</pair:ImageAvailabilityIndicator> 
    </pair:ApplicationStatusData>
    <pair:ApplicationStatusData>
        <pair:ApplicationNumber>62292372</pair:ApplicationNumber>
        <pair:ApplicationStatusCode>160</pair:ApplicationStatusCode>
        <pair:ApplicationStatusText>Abandoned  --  Incomplete Application (Pre-examination)</pair:ApplicationStatusText>
        <pair:ApplicationStatusDate>2016-11-01</pair:ApplicationStatusDate>
        <pair:AttorneyDocketNumber>681-S-23-US</pair:AttorneyDocketNumber>
        <pair:FilingDate>2016-02-08</pair:FilingDate>
        <pair:LastModifiedTimestamp>2017-06-20T21:59:26.26</pair:LastModifiedTimestamp>
        <pair:CustomerNumber>122761</pair:CustomerNumber><pair:LastFileHistoryTransaction>
            <pair:LastTransactionDate>2017-06-20</pair:LastTransactionDate>
            <pair:LastTransactionDescription>Petition Entered</pair:LastTransactionDescription> </pair:LastFileHistoryTransaction> 
        <pair:ImageAvailabilityIndicator>true</pair:ImageAvailabilityIndicator> 
    </pair:ApplicationStatusData>
    <pair:ApplicationStatusData>
        <pair:ApplicationNumber>62289245</pair:ApplicationNumber>
        <pair:ApplicationStatusCode>160</pair:ApplicationStatusCode>
        <pair:ApplicationStatusText>Abandoned  --  Incomplete Application (Pre-examination)</pair:ApplicationStatusText>
        <pair:ApplicationStatusDate>2016-10-26</pair:ApplicationStatusDate>
        <pair:AttorneyDocketNumber>1526-P-01-US</pair:AttorneyDocketNumber>
        <pair:FilingDate>2016-01-31</pair:FilingDate>
        <pair:LastModifiedTimestamp>2017-06-15T21:24:13.13</pair:LastModifiedTimestamp>
        <pair:CustomerNumber>122761</pair:CustomerNumber><pair:LastFileHistoryTransaction>
            <pair:LastTransactionDate>2017-06-15</pair:LastTransactionDate>
            <pair:LastTransactionDescription>Petition Entered</pair:LastTransactionDescription> </pair:LastFileHistoryTransaction> 
        <pair:ImageAvailabilityIndicator>true</pair:ImageAvailabilityIndicator> 
    </pair:ApplicationStatusData>
</pair:PatentApplicationList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML in your example is expanding the "pair:" part of the tags according to the schema you've used, so it doesn't match 'pair:ApplicationNumber', even though it looks like it should.

I've used element tree to extract the application numbers as follows (I've just used a local XML file in my examples, rather than the full path in your code)

Example 1:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse('ApplicationsByCustomerNumber.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for item in root:
    if 'ApplicationStatusData' in item.tag:
        for child in item:
            if 'ApplicationNumber' in child.tag:
                print child.text
```

Example 2:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse('ApplicationsByCustomerNumber.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for item in root.iter('{urn:us:gov:uspto:pair}ApplicationStatusData'):
    for child in item.iter('{urn:us:gov:uspto:pair}ApplicationNumber'):
        print child.text
```

Hope this may be useful.